# General question about simplification

Tags: integration

After done with integration I got the final answer as:

$\ln(a+4) + \ln(a-4) + C$

I can rewrite it as:

$\ln((a+4)(a-3)) + C$

But in book it is written as:

$\ln((a+4)(a-3)+C)$

Is it correct? and why?

Comment: How exactly did you rewrite $\ln(a+4) + \ln(a-4) + C$ as $\ln((a+4)(a-3)) + C\;$?

Comment: Book's answer looks wrong...

Comment: @zonnie I agree with David Mitra that the book's answer seems wrong (probably an accidental parentheses after the $C$).

Comment: No its not accidental parentheses. I did it correct. Please see the below answer given by induktio.

Comment: @zonnie He meant that the guys in charge of typing up your book's answer key probably added an accidental ) after $C$ instead of one after $(a-3)$. By the way, the guy above your comment is induktio.

Answer (score 0):

In general, with $b,M,N\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, you have that
$$
\ln_b MN = \ln_b M +\ln_b N.\tag{1}
$$
Thus, with your problem, if you actually ended up with $\ln(a+4)+\ln(a-3)+C$, then you could very well rewrite this using $(1)$ as
$$
\ln((a+4)(a-3))+C.
$$

Comment: Yeah I have done with this. But see the book answer. It is confusing. Why C is written with in parenthesis?

Comment: @zonnie People who write answer keys / solution manuals are human :) We all make mistakes and typos. I am almost 100% the parentheses was accidental.

Comment: Mistakenly it can be written in one answer. But it is almost in every solution. People who write answer keys / Solutions are human like us :) If we can point out the mistakes, why can't they.. By the way, thank you. :)